# How to send emails to addresses obtained from the result from a dynamic query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to enter email addresses based on the userids found in the query results , 
The query find the user that are violating the system and using those Ids we wish to query another table to get there full email addresses and place them in as recipients.

New Error "Msg 14624, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 238
At least one of the following parameters must be specified. "@recipients, @copy_recipients, @blind_copy_recipients".
"

Updated code .

```
declare @bodymsg nvarchar(max)
select @bodymsg = '<font face="calibiri" size="4" >Dear Users</font><br><br>
<font face="calibiri" size="5" color="red">Please Explain the Exrta Locked Faxes</font><br><br>
<font face="calibiri" size="4" >Check the Last Hour Snapshot Details Attached.<br><br>
Thanks</font></end>'

declare @users_fetched  varchar(max)
select @users_fetched = STUFF((SELECT ';' + Locked_Faxes_Last_Hour_Snap.userid from Locked_Faxes_Last_Hour_Snap
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                       ), 1, 1, '')



declare @recipients varchar(max)

SELECT 
@recipients = STUFF((SELECT ';' + concerned_staff.staff_email from concerned_staff where ( concerned_staff.staff_id in (@users_fetched) )
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                       ), 1, 1, '')

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail


@recipients = @recipients ,

@body= @bodymsg ,
@subject = 'Alert !!! Locked Faxes Violation Last Hour Snaps' ,
@profile_name = 'Database Profile 1',
@query = 'use qtel select * from dbo.Locked_Faxes_Last_Hour_Snap' ,
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename ='Locked_Faxes_Last_Hour_Snap.csv',
@query_result_separator =',',
@query_result_no_padding=1,
@exclude_query_output=1,
@append_query_error=0,
@query_result_header =1,
@body_format ='HTML',
@importance= 'HIGH';
```

Comment: And what is the error that raises with this code ?

Comment: @MarcGuillot I am trying with a non dynamic query here "@recipients = STUFF((SELECT ';' + concerned_staff.staff_email from concerned_staff where (concerned_staff.staff_id = 'umairrizvi')
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                       ), 1, 1, '')"

and its returning this error "Must declare the scalar variable "@recipients"."

Comment: To declare that variable you just need : declare @recipients varchar(max) And to use a dynamic sql you should retrieve the addresses with a sp_executesql https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql (look at the third example, with an output parameter)

Comment: Thanks @MarcGuillot let me try your advise and get back to you . :)

Comment: @MarcGuillot gave a new error this time :( 

    "Msg 8143, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 0
    Parameter '@profile_name' was supplied multiple times."

Comment: This error message says that you have assigned twice the parameter @profile_name on the EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail call.

Comment: Why don't you edit your question posting your updated code ?.

Comment: @MarcGuillot Sure Sure . : )

Comment: @MarcGuillot done sir . : )

Comment: Sorry, I can't try it, I don't have exec permissions on that stored procedure. But your first parameter assignment isn't correct. Where you have '@recipients', it should be '@recipients = @recipients',

Comment: @MarcGuillot thanks it worked ,now the last challenge is left , how to replace in the code staff_id by query results userid . any suggestions ? 

STUFF((SELECT ';' + concerned_staff.staff_email from concerned_staff where (concerned_staff.staff_id = 'replacewithqueryi')
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                       ), 1, 1, '')

Comment: Have you looked at the sq_executesql documentation ?. You need to use that to execute a dynamic query.

Comment: Thanks @MarcGuillot let me quickly check it . :) , You are really helpful.

Comment: We have to help us :-)

Comment: @MarcGuilloti tried but could not do it something goes wrong every time , can you please point me some example that fits my simple case .

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can do one of the following:

- Put your query inside a stored procedure and pass parameters.
- Construct the SQL using an expression.
- Create an expression based variable and use the variable as the source of the query.